# Small set of most different (perceptually) colors for white background regarding also visually impaireds

Tags: model, colors

**Motivation**

From time to time I need some different colors for images used in publications. Usually they are drawn on white paper meaning I prefer to choose white background color in my images. However, I also want to be sure that color-visual-impaired persons will perceive as best as possible. (Mainly focusing on red-green problem, as this is (propably most) widely distributed) As humans are limited in distinguishing colors I would concentrate on **sets containing 2 to 10 different colors**.

**Choosing the color model**

A straight forward solution is just to choose the hue value from the HSV model, not regarding the red-green weakness, etc. As other color models have been proposed, designed for humane visual perception, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space I wonder if someone have had done this work already.

*(I am aware that shapes are better distinguishable and perceivable than colors, so black-white images using different patterns/shapes/textures could lead to better results. However I think its not always possible to use such textures and beside that I want to solve this color problem as best as I could, so I am asking here :D)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With http://colorschemedesigner.com/ you are able to create up to four distinct colors and pay respect to many impairments of color perception.